# does the old api of onedrive exposed in liveconnect api's will be down(closed)?

Tags: onedrive

does the old api of onedrive (skydrive) which was exposed in liveconnect api will be down(close) with time???

the above statement was made in one of the blog
http://venturebeat.com/2015/02/24/microsoft-launches-new-onedrive-api-with-change-tracking-resumable-uploads-and-customizable-thumbnail-images/

m currently working to integrate the onedrive with our product, it is reallu tough decision to go with new apis or use older one...

pls comment, ty in advance

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you use the new API. It offers more features, better performance, and should be easier to use than the old one. We haven't announced plans for the LiveConnect API, but we're actively developing the new API.